# Difference between an error code and a message code as far as Spring validation is concerned?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am in reference to the following method from `BindingResult`:

[`BindingResult.html#resolveMessageCodes(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html#resolveMessageCodes%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

I am trying to figure out the difference between an error code and a message code. Can someone please provide an example, especially one that would illustrate **why there could be several message codes for a given error code**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because web applications are internationalized, when you reject an object and want to have a message displayed for it, you don't use a hardcoded text because that will show the same no matter the language.

Instead, you specify an error code that later server as a key to retrieving the proper message from the bundles (and now the error code is a message code from the point of view of the method that must find the proper message text).

Your error code resolves to more message codes because Spring (based on the implementation) adds some additional ones for you. Here is a snippet [from the Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch06s03.html):

> [...] What error codes it registers is determined by the MessageCodesResolver that is used. By default, the DefaultMessageCodesResolver is used, which for example not only registers a message with the code you gave, but also messages that include the field name you passed to the reject method. So in case you reject a field using rejectValue("age", "too.darn.old"), apart from the too.darn.old code, Spring will also register too.darn.old.age and too.darn.old.age.int (so the first will include the field name and the second will include the type of the field); this is done as a convenience to aid developers in targeting error messages and suchlike. [...]

The last statement is the reason there are more message codes, to have control on the message that is displayed to the user, from a generic one (e.g. "Value required") to a more specific one given the context (e.g. "A value is required for field XXX").

The [javadoc for `DefaultMessageCodesResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultMessageCodesResolver.html) explains it further and gives an example:

> For example, in case of code "typeMismatch", object name "user", field "age":
>
> 1. try "typeMismatch.user.age"
> 2. try "typeMismatch.age"
> 3. try "typeMismatch.int"
> 4. try "typeMismatch"
>
> This resolution algorithm thus can be leveraged for example to show specific messages for binding errors like "required" and "typeMismatch":
>
> at the object + field level ("age" field, but only on "user");
>       at the field level (all "age" fields, no matter which object name);
>       or at the general level (all fields, on any object).